# Downloading DLL from server - Not a Valid DLL (ERROR)

Tags: php, c++, dll

I have written an application to retrieve a library from my webserver.
When I download it, it downloads fine (no errors), but when I try to do anything with it, it fails, because of the fact that it is not a valid DLL.  Before I upload the file, I make sure it works.  My PHP download handler has a bit of authentication and then downloads using a download script.  What could be going wrong here? (No, I don't use any encryption whatsoever)

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. This site is for questions about specific problems you're having with code or a programmers tool. It's not for questions asking us to speculate about why some problem is happening with code we can't see or a vaguely described problem. Please spend some time taking the [tour] and reading through the [help] pages, especially [ask].

Answer (score 0):

It could be the stream encoding. If it's downloading as text instead of binary, then the result will be an invalid DLL.

A quick check you can do is examine the response header and ensure that it's indicating that it's a binary download (octet stream, for example). If it does indicate that it's binary, the next thing to check would be to ensure your actually receiving all the data instead of just a part of it. Check the file sizes first, and if those check out you can then do an MD5 checksum comparison. If the checksums are different then there is a problem with the download itself. What that could be would require a bit more information though.

Comment: Response header when connecting to my server reads as application/x-msdownload (which is what is what msdn specifies as the content-type for a dll).  Note: If I try to rename it to a .txt file, it does so without bringing an error like "Changing file extensions can make files not work correctly."

Comment: The universal MIME type for binary is application/octet-stream. The x-msdownload  is a vendor specific MIME type extension. I believe IE and possibly Firefox may recognize it, but you'd need to check the MIME types supported by the browser you're using.

Comment: Xyrus, I have tried using application/octet-stream, same error.  I use SSL on the domain where I download, could this be part of the problem?

Comment: Have done a checksum to ensure that the file you downloaded is actually correct? If you checksum the downloaded file and compare that to the ta checksum from the original file and they're different, then that indicates the data is somehow getting corrupted. SSL should have no impact on downloads unless one side or the other is somehow not decrypting the data (that's a different issue).